# Faster reacting Comparator

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a fully working FNAF 2 Minecraft multi-player gamemode! I plan to publish it when I am completely done and fixed all bugs. This isn't a bug, it's just that I have the right idea, but I don't know how to do it! As you may know, in FNAF 2 when certain animatronics get into your office or near it, you put on the spare Freddy head to fool them into thinking you are one of them. I have made this feature but I have to use a comparator to detect the player putting it on! And it is a few ticks (1-3) to slow! It's a tiny diffrent you might think, but it's not fair if he is holding it and in those few ticks the animatronic kills him. Any help on how to make a instant reacting comparator-type command creation? Thanks.

Comment: can you maybe get some pics so I can better see what your trying to do?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/b4aae42050d1ef360939580daa193b4d

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having the comparator, all you need to do is point your other repeating command block away from your first command block and set it to conditional.

Hope that makes sense.